# Facebook Dialog showing only in Portrait mode

Tags: facebook, orientation, facebook-ios-sdk, landscape, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a issue with the Login and sharing dialogs on my app. About a week ago they started appearing only on Portrait mode (either normal or upside down), but the landscape modes does not work.

```js
 NSArray *permissions = @[@"user_photos",
                             @"user_likes",
                             @"user_friends",
                             @"email"];

    _loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    _loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;


    [_loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:permissions fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

        if(result.isCancelled || error)
        {
            [self pressedCancel];
            return;
        }
        
        NSSet* declinedPermissions = result.declinedPermissions;
        for (NSString *declinedPermission in declinedPermissions) {

            if(!nullOrEmpty(declinedPermission))
            {
                [self pressedCancel];
                return;
            }
        }
        if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
//            self.settings.facebookToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;
            
            // Send data capture
            if([EventData sharedInstance].dataCaptureSettings.enabled)
            {
                [FacebookHelper getUserInfoWithCompletion:
                 ^(NSDictionary* userInfo, NSError* error)
                 {
                     if(!nullOrEmpty(userInfo))
                     {
                         [self captureData:userInfo];
                     } else {
                         [self captureData:nil];
                     }
                     
                      [self didSignIn];
                 }];
                return;
            } else {
                [self captureData:nil];
                [self didSignIn];
            }
        }
        
    }];
```

Here's a MPOC to replicate the issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p62vajqfk916bz1/FBTest.zip?dl=0

Any ideas what may be causing this? Or how could I make it work on Landscape mode as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone else has this issue, it was fixed on the newest Facebook SDK for iOS (4.38.1)